# Xcode SwiftUI window not shown after successful build

Tags: swift, swiftui, storyboard, nsviewcontroller

I get the following warning, on `main.storyboard`

```
Unsupported Configuartion:
Window Controller requires a content view controller
```

This is the custom class linked to the `Window Controller`, which is also the `StoryBoard Entry Point`,

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

class FirstWindowController: NSWindowController {
    
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        
        
        let contentView =  ContentView(myListModel: MyListModel())
            .environmentObject(UserData())
        
        
        self.window?.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)
       
    }
   
}
```

This is inside the `AppDelegate.swift` which is annotated as `@NSApplicationMain`.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
      
       window = NSWindow(
           contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height: 300),
            styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
            backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        window.center()
        window.setFrameAutosaveName("Main Window”)

}
```

The `main.storyboard`, `AppDelegate.swift`, and `FirstWindowController.swift` are identical to those of a project which was launching and showing the application window with no problem. I just renamed it to something else, and removed the `Core Data` support from the code. But in this project, the window doesn’t show up after successful build.

I also have checked and compared all the configuration of the storyboard for both of these projects. They seem to be totally identical.

Any help for fixing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be due to a [bug](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652621?login=true).

I removed all the other `schemes` but the one I was using in the project and the window is now loading.

Yet, the same warning is still there.

Comment: It seems that Interface Builder doesn't like it when assigning a content view controller programmatically. I was looking for a way to silence this warning, but couldn't find it. I think the only way is to create the window controller programmatically as well.